# HTML To Word (DOC/DOCX) Library

Tags: php, ms-word

Has anyone tried this library before? https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-ms-word-document-export-php/

I've got an error 500, even when I call the HtmlToDoc.class.php file alone.

**EDIT:**

Here is my index.php calling the HtmlToDoc.class.php file

```
/// Load library 
//include_once '/phpword/HtmlToDoc.class.php';

include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/phpword/HtmlToDoc.class.php");

// Initialize class 
$htd = new HTML_TO_DOC();

    $htmlContent = ' 
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> 
    <p>This document is created from HTML.</p>';

   $htd->createDoc($htmlContent, "my-document", 1);
```

For some reasons, I've the following error with the PHP file: Syntax error unexpected $EOF

```
<?php 
/** 
 * Convert HTML to MS Word document 
 * @name HTML_TO_DOC 
 * @version 2.0 
 * @author CodexWorld 
 * @link https://www.codexworld.com 
 */ 
class HTML_TO_DOC 
{ 
    var $docFile  = ''; 
    var $title    = ''; 
    var $htmlHead = ''; 
    var $htmlBody = ''; 

    /** 
     * Constructor 
     * 
     * @return void 
     */ 
    function __construct(){ 
        $this->title = ''; 
        $this->htmlHead = ''; 
        $this->htmlBody = ''; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Set the document file name 
     * 
     * @param String $docfile  
     */ 
    function setDocFileName($docfile){ 
        $this->docFile = $docfile; 
        if(!preg_match("/\.doc$/i",$this->docFile) && !preg_match("/\.docx$/i",$this->docFile)){ 
            $this->docFile .= '.doc'; 
        } 
        return;  
    } 

    /** 
     * Set the document title 
     * 
     * @param String $title  
     */ 
    function setTitle($title){ 
        $this->title = $title; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Return header of MS Doc 
     * 
     * @return String 
     */ 
    function getHeader(){ 
        $return = <<< EOH
        <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
        xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 

        <head> 
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
        <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document> 
        <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9"> 
        <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9"> 
        <!--[if !mso]> 
        <style> 
        v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} 
        o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} 
        w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);} 
        .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);} 
        </style> 
        <![endif]--> 
        <title>$this->title</title> 
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 
         <w:WordDocument> 
          <w:View>Print</w:View> 
          <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/> 
          <w:PunctuationKerning/> 
          <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing> 
          <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing> 
         </w:WordDocument> 
        </xml><![endif]--> 
        <style> 
        <!-- 
         /* Font Definitions */ 
        @font-face 
            {font-family:Verdana; 
            panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4; 
            mso-font-charset:0; 
            mso-generic-font-family:swiss; 
            mso-font-pitch:variable; 
            mso-font-signature:536871559 0 0 0 415 0;} 
         /* Style Definitions */ 
        p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal 
            {mso-style-parent:""; 
            margin:0in; 
            margin-bottom:.0001pt; 
            mso-pagination:widow-orphan; 
            font-size:7.5pt; 
                mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt; 
            font-family:"Verdana"; 
            mso-fareast-font-family:"Verdana";} 
        p.small 
            {mso-style-parent:""; 
            margin:0in; 
            margin-bottom:.0001pt; 
            mso-pagination:widow-orphan; 
            font-size:1.0pt; 
                mso-bidi-font-size:1.0pt; 
            font-family:"Verdana"; 
            mso-fareast-font-family:"Verdana";} 
        @page Section1 
            {size:8.5in 11.0in; 
            margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in; 
            mso-header-margin:.5in; 
            mso-footer-margin:.5in; 
            mso-paper-source:0;} 
        div.Section1 
            {page:Section1;} 
        --> 
        </style> 
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 
         <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1032"> 
          <o:colormenu v:ext="edit" strokecolor="none"/> 
         </o:shapedefaults></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 
         <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"> 
          <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/> 
         </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--> 
         $this->htmlHead 
        </head> 
        <body> 
EOH; 
        return $return; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Return Document footer 
     * 
     * @return String 
     */ 
    function getFotter(){ 
        return "</body></html>"; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Create The MS Word Document from given HTML 
     * 
     * @param String $html :: HTML Content or HTML File Name like path/to/html/file.html 
     * @param String $file :: Document File Name 
     * @param Boolean $download :: Wheather to download the file or save the file 
     * @return boolean  
     */ 
    function createDoc($html, $file, $download = false){ 
        if(is_file($html)){ 
            $html = @file_get_contents($html); 
        } 

        $this->_parseHtml($html); 
        $this->setDocFileName($file); 
        $doc = $this->getHeader(); 
        $doc .= $this->htmlBody; 
        $doc .= $this->getFotter(); 

        if($download){ 
            @header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors 
            @header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors 
            @header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
            @header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$this->docFile\""); 
            echo $doc; 
            return true; 
        }else { 
            return $this->write_file($this->docFile, $doc); 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Parse the html and remove <head></head> part if present into html 
     * 
     * @param String $html 
     * @return void 
     * @access Private 
     */ 
    function _parseHtml($html){ 
        $html = preg_replace("/<!DOCTYPE((.|\n)*?)>/ims", "", $html); 
        $html = preg_replace("/<script((.|\n)*?)>((.|\n)*?)<\/script>/ims", "", $html); 
        preg_match("/<head>((.|\n)*?)<\/head>/ims", $html, $matches); 
        $head = !empty($matches[1])?$matches[1]:''; 
        preg_match("/<title>((.|\n)*?)<\/title>/ims", $head, $matches); 
        $this->title = !empty($matches[1])?$matches[1]:''; 
        $html = preg_replace("/<head>((.|\n)*?)<\/head>/ims", "", $html); 
        $head = preg_replace("/<title>((.|\n)*?)<\/title>/ims", "", $head); 
        $head = preg_replace("/<\/?head>/ims", "", $head); 
        $html = preg_replace("/<\/?body((.|\n)*?)>/ims", "", $html); 
        $this->htmlHead = $head; 
        $this->htmlBody = $html; 
        return; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Write the content in the file 
     * 
     * @param String $file :: File name to be save 
     * @param String $content :: Content to be write 
     * @param [Optional] String $mode :: Write Mode 
     * @return void 
     * @access boolean True on success else false 
     */ 
    function write_file($file, $content, $mode = "w"){ 
        $fp = @fopen($file, $mode); 
        if(!is_resource($fp)){ 
            return false; 
        } 
        fwrite($fp, $content); 
        fclose($fp); 
        return true; 
    } 
}


?>
```

Comment: please add some description with code , what you have what you want and what does not work

Comment: error 500 can have many causes; permission error, php timeout, error in .htaccess code, php memory limit. Without more information we cannot help you allot. Take @BhAvikGajjar advice and add some more information

Comment: Look your PHP error log

Comment: Thanks for your replies all. When I call this file e.g. mydomain.com/HtmlToDoc.class.php in my browser, the page is empty. Do you get the same thing?

Comment: Well, i tested your code and it works correclty. Now i don't know what you are doing exactly for testing. You need to call your index.php url and not mydomain.com/HtmlToDoc.class.php

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah I've been calling index.php. But still have this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (). Some other files work fine in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space close to $return = <<< EOH like this:

$return = <<<EOH
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" ...